# Elixir: Using variables in case statement

Tags: case, constants, elixir

I've got this case statement which is giving an error 'variable constant1 is unused'. It seems to be ignoring the variables and returning the top line, so the variables obviously haven't got scope. If I replace the constant with a number 1 then it works. What is the best way of doing this in Elixir?

```
defmodule Main 
do
    def constant1, do: 1
    def constant2, do: 1
    def constant3, do: 1

    x = 1
    y = 0
    z = 0

    {a, b, c, d} = 
        case {x, y, z} do
            {constant1, constant2, constant3} -> {1, 2, 3, 4}
            {constant1, constant2, _} -> {5, 6, 7, 8}
            {constant1, _, _} -> {9, 10, 11, 12}
            {_, _, _} -> {13, 14, 15, 16}
        end

    IO.inspect {a, b, c, d}
end
```

Here is the output:

```
warning: variable constant1 is unused
  Untitled 9:15

{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Changing the constants to variables also doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have defined `constant1` being a function. When you try to use it in pattern matching, Elixir expects the variable to be there and you’ve got an error. One can’t pattern match to functions.

What you’ve wanted is likely:

```
defmodule Main do
    constant1 = 1
    constant2 = 1
    constant3 = 1

    x = 1
    y = 0
    z = 0

    {a, b, c, d} = 
        case {x, y, z} do
            {^constant1, ^constant2, ^constant3} -> {1, 2, 3, 4}
            {^constant1, ^constant2, _} -> {5, 6, 7, 8}
            {^constant1, _, _} -> {9, 10, 11, 12}
            {_, _, _} -> {13, 14, 15, 16}
        end

    IO.inspect {a, b, c, d}
end
#⇒ { 9, 10, 11, 12 }
```

Also, please remember that to pattern match to already defined value, one should use [the pin operator `^`](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/pattern-matching.html#the-pin-operator) in front of matcher, otherwise the code

```
a = 42
case x do
  a -> ...
end
```

will *overwrite* the value of `a`, setting it to the value of `x` (in the scope of `case` block, outside of `case` a will remain `42`.) With `^`, the code below will match if and only `x == 42`:

```
a = 42
case x do
  ^a -> ...
end
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. How would I use a global constant in place of the variable? I tried using the @constant1 syntax but I got an error invalid argument for unary operator ^, expected an existing variable, got: ^@constant1

Comment: You can’t. https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/2963 Basically, it is because Elixir module attributes are available _in compile time only_ and (unlike Erlang) not stored within module.

Comment: Can I have a global variable instead?

Comment: I have posted a different answer, since it worth a good formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Answering the subsequent questions about “how to,” “can I use globals,” etc.

Elixir (as all known functional languages) has no notion of “global,” since everything is immutable from the outside point of view. *True constants* are being implemented as macros. Macros are compiled during the compilation stage to AST and therefore might be used as constants inside match:

```
defmodule Constants do
    defmacro constant1 do
        quote do: 1
    end 
    defmacro constant2 do
        quote do: 1
    end 
    defmacro constant3 do
        quote do: 1
    end 
end

defmodule Main do
    require Constants

    x = 1 
    y = 0 
    z = 0 

    {a, b, c, d} =·
        case {x, y, z} do
            {Constants.constant1, Constants.constant2, Constants.constant3} -> {1, 2, 3, 4}
            {Constants.constant1, Constants.constant2, _} -> {5, 6, 7, 8}
            {Constants.constant1, _, _} -> {9, 10, 11, 12} 
            {_, _, _} -> {13, 14, 15, 16} 
        end

    IO.inspect {a, b, c, d}
end
```

The above works, because after compilation there is **no `Constants.constant1` anymore in `Main` code**: there are real values: `1`s and the code *being run* is:

```
        case {x, y, z} do
            {1, 1, 1} -> {1, 2, 3, 4}
            {1, 1, _} -> {5, 6, 7, 8}
            {1, _, _} -> {9, 10, 11, 12} 
            {_, _, _} -> {13, 14, 15, 16} 
        end
```

Hope it helps.